# how to display image from path stored in database?

Tags: php

I got the image path inserted in to database by the below code but I'm not able to display it in html page...the path for the images is `"images/"` how do i display the actual image? i tried hard but the most i got to work was to display the file name not the image.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "simple_login");

// TODO - Check that connection was successful.

$photo= "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO photo (photo) VALUES (?)");

// TODO check that $stmt creation succeeded

// "s" means the database expects a string
$stmt->bind_param("s", $photo);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$mysqli->close(

?>
```

here is what I tried to display image ...this only shows the file name with path.....

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("simple_login", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photo");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['photo'];
echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Try using the file name with an <img> tag

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_` in the top and then use `mysql_` in the bottom?

Comment: Also, top uses PDO but the bottom uses deprecated methods.

Comment: did you actually store the uploaded image somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "<img src='".$row['photo']."' />";
```

Comment: I use `echo "<img src='/home/alhelal/Pictures/GNR.png' />";` but not shown the image.